# How to access the review board site from other system via browser?

Tags: review-board

I have set-up all prerequisites and all the installation required for local  reviewboard along with rb-site, server is apache httpd with mod_wsi. Can any one help me on how to access the review bpoard which I have installed locally from different systems via web browser.

Below are the steps detailed:

yum -y install zlib zlib-devel
yum -y install openssl-devel
yum -y install memcached 
yum -y install python-devel
yum -y install python-setuptools
yum -y install patch
easy_install mysql-python
yum -y install git-core

easy_install ReviewBoard
rb-site install /var/www/ReviewBoard

While Installing rb-site :
 Domain name localhost:80
 Root Path : reviews

And other configurations are default.

All steps are executed successfully.

But I do not know how can I access the review board over browser.

Please help me?

Comment: Any help or suggestion would indeed be very helpful...

Comment: try http://ReviewBoard/reviews/. incase of errors, Review Board expects to be able to write to sitedir/htdocs/media/uploaded and sitedir/data and their subdirectories. https://<server-name>/admin for enabling admin previliege logs

Comment: For more troubleshotting details, please refer here https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.5/faq/#troubleshooting

Comment: You can also go through the [web-server-configuration manual](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/2.5/admin/installation/creating-sites/#web-server-configuration). Assuming you are using mod_wsgi, the file /var/www/ReviewBoard/conf/apache-wsgi.conf would have a ServerName (e.g. ServerName myrbserver). You should be able to open that server name in browser as `http://myrbserver`